# Open and create new post button isnt working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

The submit post button is not working, neither is the name of the user and logout button. 
Perhaps someone can help me with this?

F12 and jsintrc doesnt show anything meaningful.

**This is the html for the create new post button which is supposed to lead to a newpost.html page.**

```
<ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-nav-view>
  <ion-nav-bar></ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-view ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <ion-nav-buttons side="left" type="bar-light" ng-submit="submitPost()">
        <button class="button button-icon ion-compose" href='/tab/newpost'></button>

        <button class="button-clear" href='/tab/posts'><b>MyApp</b></button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button-clear" href="#/users/{{ currentUser.username }}">
          <img ng-src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ currentUser.md5_hash }}" 
          class="nav-pic"/>{{ currentUser.username }}
        </button>

        <button class="button-clear" href="#/auth/login" ng-click="logout()">Logout</button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
```

**This is the controller**

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth) {
    $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

    $scope.submitPost = function () {
      Post.create($scope.post).then(function (postId) {  
        $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
        $location.path('/posts/' + postId);             
      });
    };

    $scope.logout = function () {
      Auth.logout();
    };
  });
```

**And the app.js file**

```
 app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

    .state('tab.newpost', {
          url: '/newpost',
          views: {
            'tab-newpost':{
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
              controller: 'NavCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ng-submit` directive is meant to be used with form.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit)

```
<form
  ng-submit="">
...
</form>
```

use `ng-click` instead. But I don't know using `ng-click` is a good idea in `ion-nav-buttons`. Try using it on buttons or divs instead.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @bipin I just realised that as well. 

Also very silly since ng-submit does only submit and not creating a new input page. ng-click works decent in ion-nav just that I need a new controller to open the page, on clicking the button.